# Export data of one mysql table (server A) to another mysql table (server 2)

Tags: mysql

How can export "partial data" of one mysql table (on server A) to another mysql table (on server B)? My limitations are :

- I can't use replication b
- I can't use federated tables.

Please note table structure is same but database name is different.

Answer (score 1):

It will have to be a two step operation. On server 1, you use [SELECT INTO OUTFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html)

```
SELECT *  INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql/files/badatxt' FROM m_table WHERE some_condition;
```

Then after copying the file to the second server, you do a [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql/files/badatxt' INTO m_table;
```

Alternatively if the local file settings are enabled (see doc for details) you can do a LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Comment: Is it not possible to access those data files (saved on remote server) from my local server? I just want to skip the copying data files step.

Comment: if you can connect to server2 from server1 via SSH, there is no need to copy to the local machine. you can transfer directly between the two servers. Or you can use local infile directly between them

Comment: My limitation is to perform this with java code. I cant involve steps other then java. Its kind of programming assignment.

Comment: I really don't understand why you want to bring java into the picture. Why complicate matters???

Comment: But if it's really important to you , run these queries using JDBC instead of on the mysql console :))